# css style - tag within a tag within a tag

Tags: html, css, tei

I am styling a document marked up in TEI. I would like to render the "Dio" red (choice-sic-hi rend="red-corr"). I have tried the following and the word "Dio" will not render red. Here is the code:

```css
 choice sic hi[rend="red-corr"]{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<l n="21">Che fè Sufia, a chi Dio <choice>
<sic>lo cuor <hi rend="red-corr">Dio</hi></sic>
<corr cert="medium" resp="#SPM">lo cuor </corr>
</choice>crevant;<note xml:id="p21"/></l>
```

I sense I may not understand the syntax. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: the code you provided us with works. be sure to verify the code you're giving us actually reproduces the problem. read here about how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for checking to see nothing is wrong with the code. I'll follow your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work.

```css
choice sic hi[rend="red-corr"]{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<l n="21">Che fè Sufia, a chi Dio <choice>
<sic>lo cuor <hi rend="red-corr">Dio</hi></sic>
<corr cert="medium" resp="#SPM">lo cuor </corr>
</choice>crevant;<note xml:id="p21"/></l>
```